# Workflow or Calculated Value

Tags: sharepoint

I need to count/record how many times a value is selected in a pulldown.

SharePoint 2010 list question:

Let's say I have a list with a pull down containing 3 choices (red, blue and green).

Users open the list and select red.  They save/close.  Another comes in and selects blue and so forth.  This will happen randomly and indefinitely.

Is there a way to capture (in separate columns) the number of times red was selected.  The number of times blue was selected, etc...  I figure a workflow could do it but I don't know how to write a +1 value to the current item.  Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague, but you could do this using PowerShell if you just want to get the counts:

`PS C:> $q = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
PS C:> $q.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FieldName'/><Value Type='text'>red</Value></Eq></Where>"
PS C:> $result = $list.GetItems($q)
PS C:> $result.Count
8`